# Failed to connect to camera service while trying to open the front camera

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I am trying to work on this app which provides the functionality of using the front camera. I have followed a lot of tutorials rewrote the code 3-4 times searched all over the web why am I getting this exception, changed the usage of permissions and features in my manifest, I cannot come across a solution, I would really appreciate some help, I really am stuck here,

**here is my manifest:**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

**The method in my activity that I am using to call the camera,**

```
public android.hardware.Camera openCam(){

     int cameraCount = 0;
        android.hardware.Camera cam = null;
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        cameraCount = android.hardware.Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx<cameraCount; camIdx++) {
            android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                try {
                    cam = android.hardware.Camera.open(camIdx);
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    Log.e("Your_TAG", "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        return cam;
}
```

**Call to the method in the same activity**

```
@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
      case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;

      case R.id.actionSelfie:
          openCam();
          return true;

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```

Here is my stack trace:

08-15 16:36:38.759: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.762: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.764: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.768: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.782: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.782: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.783: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.783: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.784: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.787: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.787: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.788: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.788: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.790: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.792: I/SurfaceTextureClient(7134): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5dfea768)       fps:0.63, dur:9547.63, max:8855.17, min:65.20
   08-15 16:36:38.792: I/SurfaceTextureClient(7134): [STC::queueBuffer] this:0x5dfea768,   api:1, last queue time elapsed:8855.17
   08-15 16:36:38.795: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.796: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.800: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.801: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.826: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.827: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.838: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.838: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.854: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.855: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.903: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.904: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.904: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.905: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.905: V/Provider/Settings(7134):  from settings cache , name =   sound_effects_enabled , value = 1
   08-15 16:36:38.915: D/Camera-JNI(7134): getNumberOfCameras +
   08-15 16:36:38.916: D/Camera-JNI(7134): getNumberOfCameras (2) -
   08-15 16:36:38.916: D/ServiceManager(7134): The name of the service is audio
   08-15 16:36:38.917: D/ServiceManager(7134): The name of the service is audio
   08-15 16:36:38.920: E/Your_TAG(7134): Camera failed to open: Fail to connect to camera   service
   08-15 16:36:38.922: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.922: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.922: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.923: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.923: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.923: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.923: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.924: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.926: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:36:38.926: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:37:38.893: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:37:38.896: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:37:38.900: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:37:38.931: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:37:38.931: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:37:38.932: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:37:38.935: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:37:38.936: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:37:38.936: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:37:38.936: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:37:38.937: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:37:38.937: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:37:38.937: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:37:38.940: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:37:38.940: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:37:38.940: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:37:38.940: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:37:38.942: W/Trace(7134): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   08-15 16:37:38.995: V/InputMethodManager(7134): START INPUT:   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{429a4e40 V.E..... R....... 0,0-480,854} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@42982f60 controlFlags=#100
   08-15 16:37:39.011: V/InputMethodManager(7134): Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@429837b8 com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME #83}

Comment: Not sure about the API, but shouldn't you assign the return value of `android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);` to the `cameraInfo` object?

Comment: can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: Just posted it edited my question, now i have posted the stack trace as well

Comment: I still am waiting for a response, if there is something more or if there is some editing need to be done with the question please let me know, its been quite a while and m still waiting for a solution/suggestion for this problem, thanks!